# need display specific number of point only in line chart in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

need display 60 point only in line chart  and refresh display another 60

**use chartkick gem**

`index` view

```
<%= line_chart @spee.group_by_second(:created_at).maximum(:speed), refresh: 20 %>
```

`speed` controller

```
@spee = Speed.where(id_watch: current_master.id_watch)
```

This shape appear but need 60 point only
[image]

Comment: can you ellaborate more? the question isn't completely clear, where do you want to show just 60 point?

Comment: `speed` model contain `id_watch`,`speed` . i need to show 60 point in line chart.